# add horizontal line inside heading element

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate this:

[image]

So I've tried this:

```css
.test {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;

   }

 .test hr {
  display:inline;
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  border:2px solid black;
 }

 .test h1 {
  display:inline;
  float:right;
  font-size:56px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="test">
 <hr />
 <h1>Here is how the magic <br/> works.</h1>

</div>
```

As you see, is not even close.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: There is a number of different solutions, each one having strengths and draw backs. Could you tell us if it's a one off? Or will it be used more, with different words and on what background?

Comment: @Salketer Yes, It will be used across the entire website, for every title. So some titles will have more words others less. It will be a white background every time.

Comment: Do you always want it lined up with the last line in the heading?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One inner `span`, a pseudo-element and a background color to the `span` (which you indicated would always be white)

```css
h1 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.narrow {
  width: 50%;
}

.thin {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

span {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: ..5em;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: currentcolor;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>This is how the magic works</span></h1>


<h1 class="narrow"><span>This is how the magic works</span></h1>

<h1 class="thin"><span>This is how the magic works, no really it does with any font-size!</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest method...

```css
.test {
  text-align: right;
}

.test h1 {
  font-size: 56px;
  background: white;
  display: inline;
}

hr {
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.empty {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>Here is how the magic <br/><span class="empty"></span>works.</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

No flexbox! This is compatible and short.

```css
.outterDiv {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.titleText {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.rightSide {
  line-height: 0px;
}
.innerDiv {
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outterDiv">
  <h1 class="titleText">Here's how the magic</h1>
  <div class="innerDiv"></div>
  <h1 class="rightSide">works.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution using flexbox:

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#firstrow {
  text-align: right;
}

#secondrow {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
}

#text {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="firstrow">
    Here's how the magic
  </div>
  <div id="secondrow">
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="text">works</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fabio1983/vvfL1bhd/).